# Remove trailing slash on GitHub page hosted website

Tags: html, github-pages

I have a website that is now hosted on Github and works fine: **https://www.r-graph-gallery.com**

Unfortunately, that kind of URL ending with a slash does not work:

**https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/heatmap/**.

It redirects toward my `404.html` file, but without the css loading.

Note that currently both **https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/heatmap**
and

**https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/heatmap.html** work properly.

How can I make the slash ending URL work? It is crucial for me since google search always links to slash ending URLs...

I've tried to add a `.htaccess` file with redirection rules, but after some research it looks like this is not supported by gh pages.

Thanks for any hint or solution!

Comment: How about [this](https://marcgg.com/blog/2016/03/14/github-pages-jekyll/)? Or [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4440)? Or [this](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/231)? I googled "github hosting slash".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service like Cloudflare [https://www.cloudflare.com/] with GH Pages. They are completely free for a single site.

[https://dispiro.com/] is hosted on GH Pages and all traffic is routed through Cloudflare - and trailing slashes work just fine.

EDIT: 
Unfortunately there is not much available in the way of configuration on GH Pages. If you don't mind modifying your directory structure, you may be able to get it to work without a third party service.

When you go to https://www.r-graph-gallery.com GH Pages searches for `index.html` in your root directory. When you go to `/heatmap` Pages is looking for `heatmap.html`. When you go to `/heatmap/` it is looking for a `/heatmap/` directory. One solution would be to place another `index.html` file inside a `/heatmap/` directory and Pages should find the file.

```
/index.html
/heatmap/index.html
```

[The issue is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54727643/trailing-slashes-in-jekyll-github-pages-site-cause-404) Apparently

Comment: Why in the world would and should anyone need to use Cloudflare, or ANY other service, to fix such a thing?!

Comment: Edited to include possible solution

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I am 99% sure that this is actually a regression. To the best of my recollection, GitHub used to resolve `foo/bar/` to `foo/bar.html` just fine, but at some point has stopped doing so. I know because I migrated a site from Wordpress, which defaults to ending urls in trailing slashes, and it worked fine at the time, but I've just discovered that it stopped working.